# Constructor of the object created using Object.create(someprototype) in javascript

Tags: javascript, object-create

Objects created using Object.create(someObj.prototype) has it's constructor as someObj, then how come when I try to access the properties of someObj, then it gives as undefined?

```
function foo(){
    this.name1 = "Name";
    this.otherName1 = "someOtherName";
}

var fooObj = new foo();
console.log(fooObj.name1); // Name

var barObj = Object.create(foo.prototype);

console.log(barObj.constructor);  
   //Outouts: 
  // function foo(){
 //    this.name1 = "Name";                                                                                                         

 //      this.otherName1 = "someOtherName" ;
//    }


//Then why not able to access this?
console.log(barObj.name1); Outputs; // undefined
```

Comment: `this.name1` is a property attached directly to the object, not it's prototype, that's why it's undefined, as it should be

Comment: I get your point, Do mean the object created using Object.create() won't even be able to access it's constructors property?

Comment: Sure it does, if you prototype the properties, not just attach them to the object. That's why we have prototyping (at least one of the reasons), to inherit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pokjkpzb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because you haven't called the constructor yet.

Consider the following:

```
barObj.constructor(); // <--- this will call the constructor function and set this.name1 and this.otherName1
console.log(barObj.name1); // Outputs: "Name"
```

Comment: AHHH, That makes sense.

Comment: To summarize: Object.create() doesn't call the constructor, thus constructor properties were not initialized. Hence Undefined property, right? In that case let's assume, If I create *var y = Object.create(foo);* will that call the constructor, Or how'll it work? OR is it that Object.create() should always be of the form *Object.create(foo.prototype)*. Thanks.

Comment: The `Object.create();` will create a duplicate of that object, which means it will inherit that object's prototypes. Now you have a variable that holds this new object that you've just created, so if you want to initialize it, you'd need to call the constructor. This is similar to how you initialize `foo` when you call `new`.

Comment: @nitte93user3232918: No, `Object.create` does not call anything, it just creates a new, empty object, which inherits from the one passed as an argument. In your case, `barObj` inherits the `.constructor` property from the `foo.prototype` object.

Comment: @Bergi My explanation must not have been very clear - thank you for clarifying. I meant that `create()` created a duplicate of `foo` because he *passed* it in as a parameter.

Comment: @NickZ: I would personally avoid the term "duplicate" here, it's too similar to "clone" which denotes copying the properties, as opposed to setting up inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Here `barObj` is just an object linked to foo prototype object.`Object.create` won't call foo function until you call it explicitly. See below code.

`foo.call(barObj)` will call foo function with  `barObj` as it's context. Means **this** in **foo** function refers to `barObj`.

```
function foo(){
    this.name1 = "Name";
    this.otherName1 = "someOtherName";
}

var fooObj = new foo();
//console.log(fooObj); // Name

var barObj = Object.create(foo.prototype);
foo.call(barObj)

//Outouts: 
// function foo(){
//  this.name1 = "Name";                                                                                                         

//  this.otherName1 = "someOtherName" ;
//}


//Then why not able to access this?
console.log(barObj.name1);
```